# Rails devise generate model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to use 'rails generate devise model1' in rails 4, but the following error up.

```
> /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `add_route'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1417:in `decomposed_match'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1398:in `block in match'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `each'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `match'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:330:in `root'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1459:in `root'
from /home/p4/rails_tut/test_app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
from /home/p4/rails_tut/test_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/p4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/p4/rails_tut/test_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
from /home/p4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what this the internal working of rails is as this error seem to be some problem coming from 'mapping.rb'.

The following it my routes.rb

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
```

`root 'dunbs' => 'dunbs#index'`

`end`

Comment: please post the entire error, not just one line.

Comment: did you install devise at first with rails g devise:install ??

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for defining a root route is incorrect, it should be either `root to: 'dunbs#index'` or `root 'dunbs#index'`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root for more details.

Comment: It worked. But can't figure out the reason as to why this is happening as before installing rails the routing syntax worked perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - Rails routing syntax would not work before installing Rails.

Comment: Or is the syntax 'root to:' an older version support which rails 4 is accidently accepting.

Comment: Nothing accidental about it, both forms are valid. The syntax you have doesn't match that.